# Node js mysql wrapper error - Object #<Object> has no method 'table'

Tags: mysql, node.js, wrapper

I am trying a nodejs mysql wrapper which I got from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql-wrapper).Everything is working including the setup and connection. But when I try saving a piece of data into the table, I get the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'table'`. When I just console the `db` object,I get the object, no error.
Can someone tell what I miss here ?

my global.js

```
//connect to mysql
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({host : 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user : 'xxxx', password : 'xxxx', database : 'xxxx' });
connection.connect();
var wrapper = require('node-mysql-wrapper'); 
var db = wrapper.wrap(connection);
exports.db = db;
```

my app.js

```
var db = require('./global.js');
db.table('my_table').save( my_data_object );
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're exporting a separate property instead of exporting directly. So either change `exports.db = db` to `module.exports = db` *or* change `var db = require('./global.js')` to `var db = require('./global.js').db`.

Additionally, you are referencing `global.js` instead of `config.js` as you show in your question, so depending on whether or not that is a typo, that could be another issue.

Comment: sorry, the `global` thing was a typo.I corrected as you said, but now it says, `Cannot call method 'Save' of undefined` , is there a problem in exporting objects with chained methods ?

Comment: That error has an uppercase `S`. It should be lowercase `s` in `save()` as you show in your question. Also, you *may* need to place that line of code inside a `db.ready(function() {  /* here */  })` as shown in the module's readme.

Comment: yes, I was trying with a uppercase s also.No I still get the same error even after wrapping inside the ready function.Not sure what I am missing

Comment: If you have it inside the `db.ready()` callback, then I don't know what else to suggest if your table name is correct. The module seems to be officially unsupported, so you may be out of luck unless you dive into the module's code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I think I should look for some other wrapper module.